# How to use Lucene StoredFieldsFormat?

Tags: java, lucene

I'd like to enable compression of data in `lucene-4.9.0` with `CompressingStoredFieldsFormat`. But the doc's don't say anything on how the compression format has to be tied to eg the `IndexWriterConfig` or similar.

Does anyone know how this has to be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new index, the compressed format will [be used by default](http://blog.jpountz.net/post/35667727458/stored-fields-compression-in-lucene-4-1).

To double check, have a look at [Lucene49Codec](http://fossies.org/dox/lucene-4.9.0-src/Lucene49Codec_8java_source.html) -- you will see that `Lucene41StoredFieldsFormat` which is mentioned in the above linked article is used (this class directly extends `CompressingStoredFieldsFormat` but adds very little). The article also says what you need to do to turn off the compression if you need it.

Comment: Oh ok, so I probably don't have to take any actions. Unfortunately the lucene docs do not state this. Only that blog post...

Comment: That blog post is written by someone who is Lucene committer so pretty reliable ;-) [This person](http://stackoverflow.com/users/675589/jpountz) also appears here on SO from time to time so he can confirm this himself.